# Kotlin: variable in enum class can't be changed after initialization

Tags: kotlin, enums

When writing this example into the IDE:

```
enum class EnumTest {
    FOO, BAR;

    lateinit var foobar: String
}
```

I get the message `With old Native GC, variable in enum class can't be changed after initialization` on the "foobar" variable. I can't find anything about this message online. Also everything seems to work just fine, so my question is:

- When and how does this affect me?

Thank you!

Comment: A mutable property in an emum is very fragile. I'm surprised the language even allows it in the first place. Your enums should be immutable. It's also very fragile to use `lateinit` with a public `var`. That is not the intended use of `lateinit`.

Comment: Okay, but why is that? And how would i want to rewrite this code to allow this Enum to have a parameter, that I can control when it is initialized, due to it being resource heavy.

Comment: Do you know about lazy delegates? Then it wouldn’t have to be mutable. But I don’t know if that would be susceptible to the issue with the GC mentioned by the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare your values in a singleton object, set them there and reference it in the enum.

```
object Constants {
    var FOO_STR = "bla"
    var BAR_STR = "bar"
}

enum class EnumTest(val foobar: String) {
    FOO(Constants.FOO_STR),
    BAR(Constants.BAR_STR);
}
```

This code should work but also smells fishy.
Since an enum has an immutable flavor by design, I would not recommend this approach. I feel bad about posting this... but if your main problem is the resource heavy loading of these constants, maybe you do not need an enum to store those properties. Maybe just think of a simple singleton container with simple (named) properties.

Comment: Yes, i did test this and used a class to add the parameter, and to have the option to add more in the future, and then saving these inside an object. Doing this, the way i initialize these parameters are almost the same which is good. But it does still kind of feel not right. But is this essentially what you meant with the "singleton container"?

Comment: exactly. Its hard to guess, if this is the right way, I have not enough context, but yes, this is a flavor of what I meant.